# MDX equivalent Query for the below DAX CALCULATE query

Tags: dax, mdx, mdx-query

I am trying to build a Measure using `MDX` that is equivalent to the following Power BI `DAX` calculation:

```
CALCULATE(
  [Total Orders],
  'Calendar Dimension'[LAST_WEEK_FLAG]=“1"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MDX` it would likely be a new measure, that is a tuple of the specified measure and member - so something like the following. The braces are the `MDX` syntax for a tuple:

```
(
  [Measures].[Total Orders],
  [Calendar Dimension].[LAST_WEEK_FLAG].[1]
)
```